# React + Redux: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am starting with ReactJS and Redux and last few days, I am being stuck on a problem when I leave my app open in the browser for a while and then got back to it, I see there this error:
[image]

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

It's here, in my `Event.js` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { registerUser, logoutUser } from '../redux/actions/authentication';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class Event extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          ...
        }
    UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
        if(!this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
            console.log('Unauthorized - Event action');
            this.props.history.push('/');
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/api/events')
            .then((response) => {
                this.setState({events: response.data});
                console.log('events: ', this.state.events);
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log('CAUGHT IT! -> ', err);
            });
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if(nextProps.errors) {
            this.setState({
                errors: nextProps.errors
            });
        }
    }
    ...
    render() {
        const { errors } = this.state;
        const {isAuthenticated, user} = this.props.auth;

        return (...)
    }
Event.propTypes = {
    registerUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth: state.auth,
    errors: state.errors
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{ registerUser })(withRouter(Event))
```

Then, my `redux/actions/authentication.js` looks like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { GET_ERRORS, SET_CURRENT_USER } from './types'; // we list here the actions we'll use
import setAuthToken from '../../setAuthToken';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

export const registerUser = (user, history) => dispatch => {
    axios.post('/api/users/register', user)
            .then(res => history.push('/login'))
            .catch(err => {
                dispatch({
                    type: GET_ERRORS,
                    payload: err.response.data
                });
            });
}

export const loginUser = (user) => dispatch => {
    axios.post('/api/users/login', user)
        .then(res => {
            //console.log(res.data);
            const { token } = res.data;
            localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', token);
            setAuthToken(token);
            const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
            dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_ERRORS,
                payload: err.response.data
            });
        });
}

export const setCurrentUser = decoded => {
    return {
        type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
        payload: decoded
    }
}

export const logoutUser = (history) => dispatch => {
    localStorage.removeItem('jwtToken');
    setAuthToken(false);
    dispatch(setCurrentUser({}));
    history.push('/login');
}
```

And reducers - `authReducer.js`:

```
import { SET_CURRENT_USER } from '../actions/types';
import isEmpty from '../../validation/is-empty';

const initialState = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    user: {}
}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case SET_CURRENT_USER:
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: !isEmpty(action.payload),
                user: action.payload
            }
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```

`errorReducer.js` goes like this:

```
import { GET_ERRORS } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {};

export default function(state = initialState, action ) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case GET_ERRORS:
            return action.payload;
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```

and `index.js`:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import errorReducer from './errorReducer';
import authReducer from './authReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    errors: errorReducer,
    auth: authReducer
});
```

In the nabber menu, I have a link to log out the user. If the user clicks the link, I log him out like this:

```
onLogout(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.logoutUser(this.props.history);
    }
```

However, I am still unable to figure out why I am seeing the error above. What I also don't understand here is that when I get that error screen and then refresh the page, the error page disappears and I am redirected from `localhost:3000/events` to `localhost:3000`.

Comment: Can you remove everything that doesn't have to do with history? If you do, you'll probably spot the error yourself. You seem not to be passing the history to the function that calls it, but this is not a minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
withRouter(connect(...)(MyComponent))
```

and not

```
connect(...)(withRouter(MyComponent))
```

here is the [documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md#important-note)

I think `this.props.history` is `undefined` in your example because of this.

Comment: @OliviewBoisse thanks, I just tested this solution - the difference is that I am inactive for some time (say an hour) and the I look to the tab with my app, so I need to refresh the page and then I see the error (`TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`). Before, I "didn't need to" refresh the page to see this error... it unfortunately doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: can you show us the code of the Component (nabber menu) where you have the `logout` function ? to see if it's well declared with the `withRouter` HOC

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your the object you pass to the `logoutUser` function is not undefined and the `history` parameter is received in the right way. You are trying to invoke the push method on the `history` object, but in this case it tells you that the function can not be found because `history` is undefined. Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, I don't understand what actually causes that the user is redirected on that error - what part of code does that. Because when I am logged out and I try to access `localhost:3000/events`, I am promptly redirected on `localhost:3000`.  But when I am inactive for a while, then I get this error without really knowing what code "redirects" me on that error.